# create a dynamic number of dictionaries based on len of another dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
simulations = {
    'wk01' : '183',
    'wk02' : '170',
    'wk03' : '184',
}

conditions = {'slow', 'med', 'fast'}

thedicts = dict()
for cond in conditions:
    thedicts[cond] = {k: f'{d}-{cond}' for k, d in simulations.items()}
```

this creates a single dictionary with 3 nested dictionaries
rather I would create n number of dictionaries, where n must be dynamic based on the len(conditions)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the output to be?

Comment: I think you already have what you need, each one of `thedicts['slow']`, `thedicts['med']`, `thedicts['fast']` is a dictionary. You have exactly `len(conditions)` dictionaries using your current solution (they are just encapsulated in a common dictionary). Note that `conditions` is not exactly a dictionary, it's a set. Not quite the same even if they have a lot in common.

Comment: @cglacet but I don't want to explicitly write thedicts['slow'] since these conditions can change.

Comment: @sql_knievel  sample output:
slowdict = wk01: 183-slow, wk02: 170-slow, wk03: 184-slow
meddict = wk01: 183-med, wk02: 170-med, wk03: 184-med
fastdict = wk01: 183-fast, wk02: 170-fast, wk03: 184-fast

Comment: @sql_knievel You can still iterate over the `thedicts` dictionary without explicitly referring to conditions, using something like `for condition, experimental_results in thedicts.items():`. In this loop you will have dictionary in `experimental_results` together with the conditions under which you collected these data in `condition`.